Spring RestClient I/O error on GET request ConnectException: null
Performing a rest call using Spring's RestClient locally works fine for me. I have problems executing that on my pod on my Kubernetes cluster:
private fun callApi() {
        log.info("Deleting device with $id")
        restClient
            .delete()
            .uri("${getBaseUrl()}/api/${getId()}")
            .headers { it.setBearerAuth(getToken()) }
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus({ obj: HttpStatusCode -> obj.isError }, ERROR_HANDLER)
            .toBodilessEntity()
    }

This results in the following exception on my cluster. Do you have any idea where the error is coming from?
    org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error 
    on GET request for "https://my-api.com": null   at 
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriS 
    pec.createResourceAccessException(DefaultRestClient.java:584) ~ 
    [spring-web-6.1.13.jar!/:6.1.13]    at
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriS 
    pec.exchangeInternal(DefaultRestClient.java:498) ~[spring-web- 
    6.1.13.jar!/:6.1.13]    at 
org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriS 
    pec.retrieve(DefaultRestClient.java:458) ~[spring-web- 
    6.1.13.jar!/:6.1.13]
    
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: null  at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl. 
    java:951) ~[java.net.http:na]   at 
java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFac 
    ade.java:133) ~[java.net.http:na]   at 
org.springframework.http.client.JdkClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(Jd 
    kClientHttpRequest.java:102) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar!/:6.1.13]  at 
org.springframework.http.client.AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.exec 
    uteInternal(AbstractStreamingClientHttpRequest.java:70) ~[spring- 
    web-6.1.13.jar!/:6.1.13]    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(Abstr 
    actClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.1.13.jar!/:6.1.13] at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriS 
    pec.exchangeInternal(DefaultRestClient.java:492) ~[spring-web- 
    6.1.13.jar!/:6.1.13]    ... 35 common frames omittedCaused by: 
    java.net.ConnectException: null at 
java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.toConnectException(Uti 
    ls.java:1028) ~[java.net.http:na]   at 
java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(Pl 
    ainHttpConnection.java:227) ~[java.net.http:na] at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.checkRetryConne 
    ct(PlainHttpConnection.java:280) ~[java.net.http:na]    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.lambda$connectA 
    sync$2(PlainHttpConnection.java:238) ~[java.net.http:na]    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableF 
    uture.java:934) ~[na:na]    at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(C 
    ompletableFuture.java:911) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Comple 
    tableFuture.java:510) ~[na:na]  at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(Com 
    pletableFuture.java:1773) ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPo 
    olExecutor.java:1144) ~[na:na]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadP 
    oolExecutor.java:642) ~[na:na]  at 
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]Caused by: 
    java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null  at 
java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureOpen(SocketChannelImpl. 
    java:202) ~[na:na]  at 
java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.beginConnect(SocketChannelImp 
    l.java:786) ~[na:na]    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.jav 
    a:874) ~[na:na] at 
java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.lambda$conne 
    ctAsync$1(PlainHttpConnection.java:210) ~[java.net.http:na] at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessControll 
    er.java:571) ~[na:na]   at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync 
    (PlainHttpConnection.java:212) ~[java.net.http:na]  ... 9 common 
    frames omitted

If you need more information please tell me. Any hints are appreciated.

Check what getBaseUrl() returns and whether you have configured it correctly. You can also get inside the pod and do a telnet/curl to see if it can reach the URL it returns..
